# RESTish add, edit, delete urls for jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I would like to have RESTish urls for the add, edit and delete functionality of jqgrid.

Each row has an id and I would like to edit / delete using url like
/mywebapp/myitem/id

id is a value of one of the columns of the grid. In more advanced use case, I might require to combine values from multiple columns.

Are these things possible?

In case of add, the post will be to /mywebapp/myitem as id will not be known. How can I specify the action verb?

I have already seen -

- [JQGrid Setting different URLs for add,edit,delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736633/jqgrid-setting-different-urls-for-add-edit-delete)
- [Add/edit/delete in jqGrid with Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477090/add-edit-delete-in-jqgrid-with-web-api)

Comment: The solution heavy depend on version of jqGrid and the fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7), which you use. The editing mode (form editing, inline editing, cell editing) could be important too (depend on version and the fork used). The most easy would be implementation in free jqGrid (the fork, which I develop) because I implemented support of `url` (`editurl`) defined as callback function. It allows to build URL dynamically based on rowid and editing mode (add or edit).

Comment: Hi, I am using http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334